# How to denote the contribution of a co-author who did not do any experiments or analyses?

Tags: authorship

We are resubmitting a paper. One co-author was part of the project from the beginning, assisted in all group discussions, gave intellectual feedback, but did not do any experiments/analyses. He also wrote a small part of the discussion. What should I write regarding his/her contributions in the respective section?

Comment: Sounds like he contributed to planning of the project, interpreting the data (I guess - by giving feedback and contributing in discussions) and writing the paper. What is the problem? What is special about this case?

Comment: You should write exactly that. Author contribution sections are precisely for you to describe how people contributed. Why does that not satisfy you

Comment: "Investigation, discussions, writing", if you want to be succinct.

Answer (score 3):

This does not sound like a special case at all, but rather like a typical contribution of a supervisor.
When describing such a co-author’s contributions, I would let myself be inspired by other similar descriptions for supervisors.
The definite answer may depend on the particular style of this section and details of the contribution, but one suggestion would be:

> X designed the study, supervised the research, and wrote the manuscript.